# Ping in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

I can ping using console app, but I want to ping from ASP.NET, the problem is that, ping object doesn't show ping.send(....).
Is it not possible to ping from ASP.NET Web App?

for image please visit : http://coscientech.blogspot.com/2010/09/ping-trouble-aspnet.html

Directives are : `using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.NetworkInformation;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Text;`

Comment: Unless you have control over the server you will be deploying on, there is a good chance that outgoing ping requests will be blocked a firewall.

Comment: but, in the temporary server that is where ctrl+f5ed web apps go, I think it should let me! that's not the point anyway, the point , why I can't see, pingsend.send(...)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know if this is your case, but in general sending raw packet, done by ping, requires administrator rights on Windows. So most likely your ASP.NET page doesn't have enough privileges to send a ping packet. You can check this by copying the logic to regular application and running this application in different conditions. This will show you when Ping would work and when it wouldn't.

Comment: In console app, this is running well, given that text fields are converted to readlines();